# Rows to columns not working well

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and what I would like to do is from the following result:

```
Answer          QuestionID
Low Effort      1
Satisfied       2
Yes             3
Not Applicable  4
Likely          5
Very patient  and an excellent help. The TV is working fine now thanks again Ria   
Peter   6
Excellent       8
```

produce something like:

```
1          |2            |3         |4             ....  |8
Low Effort |Satisfied    |Yes       |Not Applicable....  |Excellent
```

I am using this query but is not working properly:

```
select 
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
from
    (select 
         Answer, QuestionID
     from 
         [dbo].[SurveyDataDetail]) d
pivot
    (max(Answer)
     for QuestionID in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    ) piv;
```

Any comments?

Comment: You haven't produced something someone can just copy/paste and execute to test; they'd have to first create a `SurvyDataDetail` table, and then insert sample data. (I.e. you haven't produced a [mcve]) _Note you could easily use a table variable to produce a self-contained example: `declare @SurveyDataDetail table (...) insert @SurveyDataDetail values ...`_

Comment: Also when you say something is "_not working properly_" that's not very informative. In what way is it not working? ** Are you getting an error message? ** Are you getting too many rows? ** Are you getting incorrect results? (_This extra information is particularly important when you've failed to provide a [mcve], but is advisable to include regardless._)

Comment: Please note that in SQL, subtleties of your table definition can have an effect on how your queries behave. Which is why [mcve] is so important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quotes.  Use escape characters:

```
select [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
```

Single quotes should only be used for string and constants.

The full query would be:

```
select [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]
from (select Answer, QuestionID
      from [dbo].[SurveyDataDetail]
     ) d
 pivot (
     max(Answer)
     for QuestionID in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9])
    ) piv;
```

Comment: if I do this I get an errorselect 
 1 as [1]
 ,2 as [2]
 ,3 as [3]
 ,4 as [4]
 ,5 as [5]
 ,6 as [6]
 ,7 as [7]
 ,8 as [8]
 ,9 as [9]


from (
       select   SDD.QuestionID
   ,SDD.Answer
FROM [dbo].[SurveyDataDetail] SDD
) x
PIVOT
( max(Answer) for QuestionID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) --ERROR HERE
) qt